# Выполнение одного и того же действия с разных событий (MVVM?)

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm

Помогите разобраться со структурой программы. Пытаюсь грамотно построить логику, для дальнейшей безпроблемной модификации и развития кода.

Есть достаточно уже большой продукт, по тихонечку переписываю код, приводя его в порядок, чтобы можно было дальше его развивать. Пытаюсь изучить правильное оформление кода. В WPF познакомился с binding, но в winforms, что-то не могу разобраться, как его использовать.

Можете привести пример маленького фрагмента кода, как его использовать, в простенькой задачке:

- Есть Edit edit1
- Главное меню - копировать
- Контекстное меню у эдита - копировать
- Кнопка на панели - копировать
- Кнопка на форме - копировать

Как правильно реализовать функционал копирования данных из edit1 в буфер обмена, чтобы не дублировать код? Полагаю нужно смотреть в сторону ICommand, но так и не получается разобраться...

Если не сложно, приведите фрагмент кода, как это оформлять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаком с WinForms, но конкретно насчёт копирования:

- в главном меню помещаете пункт меню Copy с командой ApplicationCommands.Copy (или какой там аналог в WinForms). Никакого OnClick не нужно.
- у `Edit`'а контекстное меню должно быть само по себе
- кнопка на панели/форме: можно в WinForms добавить команду к кнопке? Если да, добавляйте ApplicationCommands.Copy, никакого OnClick не нужно.

**Обновление**

Тут тоже по идее просто. Надо забиндить Visibility галочки и состояние кнопки на CanExecute команды. (Но это в WPF, как организовывается Binding в WinForms, не знаю.)

---

В любом случае, состояние лучше всего записать в команду, а отображением состояния на контролы пускай занимается уровень View.

Comment: @vladd, да, не подумал, что приведенный с потолка пример по-другому можно решить :-) 
А если ещё добавить к примеру, что рядом с пунктами меню нужно поставить галочку, если в буфере есть текст, а кнопки должны принять статус "зажатой". :-)

Comment: Сейчас на ум приходит только сделать единый обработчик для них и явно прописать в нем, что должно с контролами произойти, но это решение а лоб и опять-таки, форма будет заниматься логикой...